# Advice on converting from Nested Listviews in JQueryMobile 1.4

Tags: jquery-mobile

I found all this sample code using a listview and just adding nested `<ul><li></li></ul>` to it.

then you could click on the top level, and drill down to the next.

This seemed like a good way to navigate content that is structured in a hierarchical structure.

What is the suggested alternative in 1.4?

Comment: Have a look at collapsible and collapsibleset

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-nested-lists/